# What happens if 2 parties try to arbitrage the same opportunity in Uniswap?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Let's say we have this arbitrage opportunity for a 10% gain on UNISWAP, with a total amount of 2ETH  possible (if the trade is bigger, the price difference will become 0).

What happens if there's 2 different parties adding the same 2ETH token swap sequence to the block? Who has priority? Will they both go through?

Answer (score 0):

This is completely up to the miner who mines the block. Both could be included, one of them or none. It will most likely depend on their transaction fees and whether both transactions get propagated to the miner in time to get in the block.

If the fees are high enough, the miner has incentive to include both. When that happens, one of the transactions will end up executing before the other and will end up grabbing the opportunity for itself while the other will execute when it's already gone. If it's a contract call and has a built-in check to make sure the arbitrage opportunity actually exists it might just revert instead.

This happens very often in reality and is one of the typical sources of [MEV](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/mev/). There are bots watching transactions and constantly trying to get in front of arbitrage opportunities found by others.